# Changing Rviz item properties on-the-fly

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Lets say I have a project involving Rviz and some display types, say, a PointCloud2 I'm listening to.
If I wanted to change the cloud coloring, shpere size, or topic, for example, but through a command from within a node and/or an rqt gui incorporating Rviz, what would I be looking for? Is it dynamic reconfigure or are there more / other ways of doing so?

I'm just looking for a short pointing in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it because I can't seem to find the correct keyword for this.

Many thanks,
Steve

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270610/changing-rviz-item-properties-on-the-fly/) by [StevenCoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/30608/stevencoral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2017-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[how to programmatically add/remove displays in rviz](https://answers.ros.org/question/9722/how-to-programmatically-addremove-displays-in-rviz/)

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [StevenCoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/30608/stevencoral/) on 2017-09-20**:
forgot to say thank you